# OpenCL Buffer caching behaviour

Tags: caching, opencl, specifications

I've always been wondering about the caching behaviour of global data in OpenCL.

Lets say I have a pointer to global memory in a kernel.
Now I read the location the pointer points to.
Later in the kernel I might need the same data again, so I read it again through the pointer.

Now the question is, will this data be cached, or will it be reread from global memory every single time because other threads could have modified it?
If it's not cached, then I'd have to make a local copy every time so I don't lose tons of performance by constantly accessing global memory.

I know this might be vendor specific, but what do the specs say about this?

Answer (score 3):

There is some caching but the key to great GPU compute performance it is move "accessed many time" data to private or shared local memory and not re-read it. In a way, you can think of this as "you control the caching". In OpenCL this would be done in your kernel (in parallel!) and then you'd have a memory barrier (to ensure all work items have finished the copy) then your algorithm has access to the data in fast memory. See the matrix multiply example (since each column and row contributes to multiple output values, copying them to shared local memory accelerates the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I've read the Nvidia OpenCL best practices paper. But moving something to shared memory only makes sense if the required data is, as the word says, shared among the threads. This is not the case in my Application. Only moving it to private memory would make sense. But my question is related thowards what the standard defines. I don't want to make assumptions. I know that images are/can be cached. But buffers?

Comment: The standard defines no caching behaviors whatsoever. It is up to each implementation. Your most portable solution is going to read values from global memory (buffers) _once_ and not rely on caching for re-reads to be fast.

Comment: But the standard has to define the allowed caching behaviour. Can you tell me where I can read that up in the specification?

Comment: The standard does not have to define caching behavior. It is up to an implementation.

Comment: I said "But the standard has to define the ALLOWED caching behaviour.".

Answer (score 0):

Those who want benefits of local cashing for work-items within a work-group, for example on FPGAs, can read this paper by Andrew Ling at IWOCL2017 https://www.iwocl.org/wp-content/uploads/iwocl2017-andrew-ling-fpga-sdk.pdf. It is a good example of having correct usage of local caches and clever communication for dataflow computing. Those who want convenience of cache in parallel peer-to-peer setting and still have hardware do this for them should consider POWER8 or POWER9 chips. These conveniences come at the cost: caching global or virtual memory cluster interconnect may have to have several TBs of bandwidth. Real question is: What is the value of caching for dataflow compute e.g. ML, especially on clusters, vs. reducing communication and increasing data reuse by other means.