# Is it possible for Opencl to cache some data while running between kernels？

Tags: opencl

I currently have a problem scenario where I'm doing graph computation tasks and I always need to update my vertex data on the host side, iterating through the computations to get the results. But in this process, the data about the edge is unchanged. I want to know if there is a way that I can use OpenCL to repeatedly write data, run the kernel, and read the data, some unchanged data can be saved on the device side to reduce communication costs. By the way, I am currently only able to run OpenCL under version 1.2.

Comment: good question. Are you using FPGA or GPU?

Comment: I am going to use OpenCL on Intel FPGA, its SDK only supports version 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Question** 1:

*Is it possible for Opencl to cache some data while running between kernels*

---

**Yes**, it is possible in OpenCL programming model. Please check [Buffer Objects, Image Objects and Pipes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/pdf/OpenCL_API.pdf) in OpenCL official documentation. Buffer objects can be manipulated by the host using OpenCL API calls.

Also the following OpenCL StackOverflow posts will further clarify your concept regarding caching in OpenCL:

- [OpenCL execution strategy for tree like dependency graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842457/opencl-execution-strategy-for-tree-like-dependency-graph)
- [OpenCL Buffer caching behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915784/opencl-buffer-caching-behaviour)
- [Memory transfer between host and device in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178947/memory-transfer-between-host-and-device-in-opencl)

And you need to check with caching techniques like [double buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837065/opencl-double-buffering-using-two-command-queues-for-a-single-device) in OpenCL.

---

**Question** 2:

*I want to know if there is a way that I can use OpenCL to repeatedly write data, run the kernel, and read the data, some unchanged data can be saved on the device side to reduce communication costs*

---

**Yes**, it is possible. You can either do it through batch processing or data tiling. Because as the overhead associated with each transfer, batching many small
transfers into one larger transfer performs significantly better than making each
transfer separately. There can be many examples of batching or data tiling. One cane be this:
[OpenCL Kernel implementing im2col with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953823/opencl-kernel-implementing-im2col-with-batch)

---

**Miscellaneous**:

---

- If it is possible, please use the latest version of OpenCL. Version 1.2 is old.
- Since you have not mentioned, programming model can differ between hardware accelerators like FPGA and GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the current version 1.2 is limited by the SDK provided by Intel FPGA, I will study your answer later to solve the problem and provide feedback.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that you are using FPGA. Because then I can further update my answer to help you. Give me some more time. And which particular FPGA is it?

Comment: I am using Intel Arria 10 GX 1150 FPGA